# How do I run a script using a BAT file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, batch-file, sqlcmd

I would like to have a BAT file open a sql server script. Currently I have this code in the sql file:

```
declare @path varchar(255), @mydb varchar(50)
SELECT @mydb = 'timeclockplus'
select @path = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\MSSQL\Backup\' 
            + @mydb + '-' + convert(varchar(8),getdate(),112) + '.bak'
BACKUP DATABASE @mydb TO DISK = @path
```

How do I open this SQL file from a BAT file?

I am currently trying to run it like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\osql -E 
   -S Sql server-hl7\timeclockplus timeclockplus.sql -oresults.txt
```

but OSQL does not exist in the BINN directory,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should invoke the [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) command-line tool from your batch file. Assuming your sql file is "backup.sql", the command line would be something like:

```
sqlcmd -E -S yoursqlinstance -i backup.sql
```

`-E` uses trusted connection, replace with `-U` and `-P` if you need to specify a SQL username and password. See also [this article with examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702.aspx).

Comment: +1: I was too slow, additional link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702.aspx

Comment: Good link, added it to the answer.

Comment: Good day sir, But how is the whole coding on how to create the batch file?

Answer (score 4):

```
sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 /E -i MySqlScript.sql
```

Replace /E with /U and /P if you don't have trusted connection

Answer (score 3):

If you want a much better answer, here it is:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: batch file for sql query
SET FIELDVAL=Empty
SET DBNAME=MYDB
SET SQLSTRING=SELECT column_name(s)^
 FROM table_name1^
 INNER JOIN table_name2^
 ON table_name1.column_name=table_name2.column_name^
 AND table_name2.field=%FIELDVAL%
ECHO !SQLSTRING!

ECHO.
sqlcmd.exe -b -S localhost -E -d !DBNAME! -Q "!SQLSTRING!" -W
ECHO Query is done. Hit any key to close this window....
pause>nul
```

Answer (score 0):

Start > Run > Type Cmd.

MyDrive:\Mypath\Mybat.bat

=)