# How to run .sql file from a batch file?

Tags: sql, windows, sql-server-2008, scheduling

I am running sql server 2008 express and i need to schedule some stored procedures to run nightly...so i have built out these .sql files which i would want to run from .bat file...i need to know the command to execute these .sql files one by one and store their results i guess...can anyone help me out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i run a script using a BAT file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258975/how-do-i-run-a-script-using-a-bat-file)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I answered this [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258975/how-do-i-run-a-script-using-a-bat-file/3258991#3258991):

You should invoke the [sqlcmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258975/how-do-i-run-a-script-using-a-bat-file/3258991#3258991) command-line tool from your batch file. Assuming your sql file is "backup.sql", the command line would be something like:

```
sqlcmd -E -S yoursqlinstance -i backup.sql
```

`-E` uses trusted connection, replace with `-U` and `-P` if you need to specify a SQL username and password. See also [this article with examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

See the `sqlcmd` utility:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702.aspx

This allows you to run sql scripts from the command line

Answer (score 1):

osql:

http://www.di-mgt.com.au/osqlUtility.htm

Answer (score 1):

I don't use SQL Server, but a batch file is just a list of DOS commands. So whatever you use to execute SQL files from the commandline can be used in a batch file.

A quick google search turns up:

```
sqlcmd -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you :

```
sqlplus UserName/Password@DataBase @C:\sqlFolder\sqlFile.sql
```

P.S : Don't forget to add the command "commit;" at the end of sql file (sqlFile.sql), this command order Oracle to save performed changes in database